# Wifi network not discoverable - neighbours' wifi networks seen

Tags: wireless-networking, router

I'm running into a problem where my wifi adapter occasionally fails to discover my home wifi network. My other devices are able to discover the home wifi network successfully. I also checked that SSID broadcast is enabled on the router.

I'm running a Windows 10 machine with a Realtek 802.11n 2.40 GHz wireless adapter. Rebooting the router helps sometimes, but not always. Rebooting the computer, uninstalling/reinstalling network drivers won't help.

After several weeks of search, I was able to figure out the problem. I thought I'll document the issue and the solution, as it might help others.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be with the wifi channel that the router picks to broadcast. My wifi adapter only searches for wifi on channels 1 to 11, but my router was configured to pick channels automatically. If the channels 12 or 13 were picked, the adapter wouldn't be able to discover the network. Changing the router channel to 1 fixed the problem.